# Shut off a low-current circuit beneath a certain voltage

Tags: batteries, diodes, lipo

I have a circuit that requires only 2mA of current. I need to turn it off when my LiPo drops below 3.5V. The LiPo is not at risk of overcharging, because the charging circuit is separate from this circuit.

What's the best way to turn off this half of the circuit when the supply voltage drops below 3.5V? Can I just use any old diode?

[image]

Comment: Called "undervoltage lockout". You can buy purpose built ICs, many microcontrollers have the function built in or you can use a voltage reference and transistor.

Comment: Due to my low current usage, can I just use a zener diode?

Comment: The trouble with all of these circuits is ... how much current are you willing to waste turning it off....

Comment: @KMmmm How exactly would you use the zener diode? Make a schematic.

Comment: I have added a diode to a circuit

Comment: The diode works @ 3.7 V but shuts off @ 3.50 V

Comment: The way you have connected the diode it just drops 0.7 V so your circuit will be permanently low voltage. It doesn't stop discharging either. If you reverse the diode you will lose 3.5 V so your circuit will have almost no voltage. You will require a more complex solution. Note that there is a schematic button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: Would this be an appropriate IC?  @τεκ https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/308/UC3842B-D-116980.pdf

Comment: @KMmmm Wrong type of IC entirely. Look for a voltage supervisor or battery protection IC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just an idea. I've not tested it. But it gets a simple idea across, I think. And it only uses parts you'd truly expect to find in a junk box of parts:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy4lUom.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The basic idea is to turn \$Q_1\$ into a comparator without using a zener. It's base is one input and is presented with a voltage divider made up of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$. It's emitter is the other input to the comparator. But instead of a zener, it just uses a common diode. \$C_1\$ isn't strictly necessary, especially with \$R_5\$ added for hysteresis (discussed later), but just a little bit goes a long way in reducing noise at the emitter of \$Q_1\$.

Some feedback is applied from the output (on/off state) at the collector of \$Q_2\$ via \$R_5\$, so that there is a tiny bit of hysteresis in the circuit. You can adjust the divider, \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$, until it triggered approximately in the right place for you. But \$R_5\$ arranges things so that the turn-off point and the turn-on points are slightly separated from each other to give it a nice "snap" response that ignores some noise. You can reduce the value of \$R_5\$ for more noise immunity. But there is a trade-off, so adjust it in small steps.

It's pretty simple, so I'm fairly sure it will work. I arranged this with the idea of your load's current. But it should be fine over a reasonable range.

---

Trevor makes a great point about excess current through the \$R_3\$, \$Q_1\$, and \$D_1\$ path, just to run a \$2\:\text{mA}\$ load. He's right. My goal above was to use nothing but junk box parts. And in my past, NFET and PFET devices with low thresholds were NOT junk box parts (for me.) But they certainly may be, today. And besides, he is quite right about the excess current in the above circuit.

If you have, or can get a BSS84 or something similar, regarding thresholds, then the following circuit is much lighter on your battery source:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqxYaOm.png)</sup>

I did say that the first circuit was conceptual, only. But Trevor is dead right about using a PFET for \$Q_2\$ as a better choice in a circuit like this. So if you have one of these, feel free to modify the idea as just shown.

You can also use \$R_3\$ in the circuit to adjust the exact threshold. Making it smaller or larger will change the load on the divider and move the threshold around a bit.

Comment: Eeek that's a lot of current through Q2,Q1 and D1 when it is on... like 9mA,  much more than the 2mA the load takes... The hardest part of this, what seems like a simple task, is not adding to the burden of the battery. Q2 needs to be a mosfet.

Comment: @Trevor_G Yeah. I did say it was just a concept. And you are quite right. A MOSFET would make a much better \$Q_2\$. I should update that with something that has a very low threshold and change \$R_3\$. I'll get to that and make the fix. Do you have a nice suggestion for the PFET? BSS84?

Comment: @Trevor_G Your thoughts have been added. Hopefully, in a satisfactory way.

Comment: Its b-all current so a small signal, low Ron one would be plenty.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a zener but you need to combine it with some addition transistors to do what you want.

Here when the battery voltage is greater than the zener voltage plus a diode drop the MOSFET is on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNtkXN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, accuracy is dependent on the Zener and transistor characteristics and will be temperature sensitive. Whether that is close enough for your application I can not tell.

Answer (score 1):

A more accurate method is to use a micro-power comparator with a built in band-gap reference, like an [LTC1541](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/15412fd.pdf), to drive a MOSFET.

The trade off is you will consume a few micro-amps, ~6uA, when the power is off, however it will switch much more accurately at the voltage you desire, with some hysteresis, and be a lot less temperature sensitive.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7SZy5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above uses the op-amp in the LTC as another comparator to invert the output of the actual comparator to drive the P-MOSFET gate. That may or may not be problematic. If you don't mind switching the low side this version, with an N-MOSFET, may be better.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp34vD.png)</sup>